# How can I post an answer to this question on SuperUser?

Tags: support, answers, protected-posts

I viewed a topic on this site which hasn't really been answered for 4 years:

> “[How to go to the next/previous picture using the Windows 10 default photo viewer?](https://superuser.com/q/1147652/167207)”

On reading the responses, it gave me some clues and I was able to solve the problem.

When I tried to post the solution, I was unable as I must have 50 points or some such rubbish.

So the point is, how can you post an answer on SuperUser to let other people in on the answer, that has clearly been troubling people for years and (based on early comments) is actually now much worse than it was when the question was first raised. (ie buttons used to exist, but were greyed out. Now they don’t even exist)

Answer (score 8):

[The question](https://superuser.com/questions/1147652/how-to-go-to-the-next-previous-picture-using-the-windows-10-default-photo-viewer) you're referred to has been [protected](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) due lot of drive-by "answers" which doesn't really answer the question but are some sort of "I have this too" or "this is sucks" posts which the answer section isn't really meant for.

[image]

Clicking on the Highly active question tells you why it was protected. You need 10 points, not 50 - you can [earn rep](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) by answering posts, suggesting edits etc - 10 rep is not that big of a number, tbh.

---

The 50 rep requirement is for posting comments - comments aren't meant to be answers but rather ephemeral clarifications or notes that are bound to be removed at any point.

Finally,

> So the point is, how can you post an answer on SuperUser to let other people in on the answer, that has clearly been troubling people for years and (based on early comments) is actually now much worse than it was when the question was first raised. (ie buttons used to exist, but were greyed out. Now they don't even exist)

This doesn't seem like an answer, at max a comment which doesn't really help in any way. As an answer it'd most likely get flagged as not an answer (and precisely why the question was protected in the first place - to prevent non-answers from being posted)

Comment: To add to your answer, the OP can answer questions that are not protected but can't comment yet. He can comment when he reaches 50 points.

Comment: Good point about comment, I'll add that - and that matches the 50 rep requirement

Comment: So, apparently I can't answer the question. Pity. The answer is quite simple as it happens.

Comment: @john - Answer a single question and receive 5 upvotes, that’s all it takes, to answer a protected question.  I could unprotect that question, but it has 3 extremely low quality answers that were deleted, answer a different question then answer that question.  After 5 years the community can wait for your answer